# React ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().width on Change is always one step behind

Tags: reactjs

I have this code:

Refs:

```
const metaRef = useRef( null );
    const urlRef = useRef( null );
    const descRef = useRef( null );
```

(These refs are assigned to 3 different HTML spans)

```
const handlePixelChange = ( value ) => {
        console.log( value );
    };

    const handleInputChange = ( e ) => {

        const pixelLengthBundled = {
            title: metaRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width.toFixed(),
            url: urlRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width.toFixed(),
            desc: descRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width.toFixed()
        };

        handlePixelChange( pixelLengthBundled );
```

(This code is onChange on three different input fields, in which the previous span elements are the width of the text inside the input field. So if a user types "Hello", then the span element is the width of the text "Hello", which I capture inside of the handleInputChange function, bundled into an object, and sending it to another function).

My issue:

When I log the value of the widths of the refs, it is always one step behind. For example:

User enters a single character, when logging the value, it says that the width is 0 (of the span element), but when inspecting the span element, it is 5 pixel wide. and then when enterering the second character, it then shows the width as 5 pixels, as it should at the start.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score -1):

You could add another ref to the input element and then with a auto-width style get the input width

component.css

```
input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

component.jsx

```
const inputRef = useRef(null); // Assign this ref to your input

...

const handleInputChange = ( e ) => {
    const inputWidth = e.target.getBoundingClientRect().width.toFixed();
    /* or const inputWidth = inputRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width.toFixed(); */
    /* Rest of code */
}
```

Comment: Why should he do that? What does that do? How does it answer the question? [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

I just encountered the same issue. The only solution I've found so far has been to check the width inside of a `useLayoutEffect` and then store this value.

Example:

```
const [width, setWidth] = React.useState(0);

React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => setWidth(imageRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width),
    100
  );
});
```